# How many people are affected by hepatocellular carcinoma (HCC) worldwide today?

Tags: cancer, liver

Does anybody know how I can learn **how many people** are affected by **hepatocellular carcinoma (HCC)** worldwide today?

I need this information for a research study; I tried to search on Google but I only found a [paper by Rawla and colleagues](https://dx.doi.org/10.5114%2Fwo.2018.78941) reporting 14 milion cases in 2012. I need more recent statistics.
Does anyone know how I can find it?

I also searched on the World Health Organization (WHO) website but could not find this information.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Global incidence for HCC, 2018:** 
[What is the global incidence of hepatocellular carcinoma (HCC) worldwide? (Medscape, 2019)](https://www.medscape.com/answers/197319-39196/what-is-the-global-incidence-of-hepatocellular-carcinoma-hcc-worldwide):

> Worldwide, liver cancer was the fifth most common cancer and the third
>   most common cause of cancer deaths in **2018,** with an estimated **841,080
>   new cases and 781,631 deaths.** The incidence was highest in East Asia,
>   at 17.7 per 100,000 population (26.8 in males and 8.7 in females),
>   followed by Micronesia, northern Africa, Southeast Asia, and
>   Melanesia. The incidence was lowest in south-central Asia (2.5 per
>   100,000) and western Asia (4.0 per 100,000). By comparison, the
>   incidence rate was 6.6 per 100,00 in North America and 5.3 per 100,000
>   in western Europe. Overall, the incidence rate of liver cancer is
>   approximately three times higher in males than in females. Mortality
>   figures mirror the incidence figures.

**2) Global incidence, prevalence and mortality for HCC, 2018:** [Hepatocellular carcinoma, The New England Journal of Medicine, 2019)](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMra1713263): 
[Figure 1](https://www.nejm.org/na101/home/literatum/publisher/mms/journals/content/nejm/2019/nejm_2019.380.issue-15/nejmra1713263/20190405/images/img_medium/nejmra1713263_f1.jpeg) shows a worldwide map of incidence, prevalence and mortality of HCC per 100,000 population in 2018.

**3) 1-year global prevalence of liver cancer, 2018:** Worldwide data by country from Global Cancer Observatory, 2018: [a map](https://gco.iarc.fr/today/online-analysis-map?v=2018&mode=population&mode_population=continents&population=900&populations=900&key=asr&sex=0&cancer=11&type=2&statistic=1&prevalence=1&population_group=0&ages_group%5B%5D=0&ages_group%5B%5D=17&nb_items=5&group_cancer=1&include_nmsc=1&include_nmsc_other=1&projection=globe&color_palette=default&map_scale=quantile&map_nb_colors=5&continent=0&rotate=%255B10%252C0%255D) and [a table](https://gco.iarc.fr/today/online-analysis-map?v=2018&mode=population&mode_population=continents&population=900&populations=900&key=asr&sex=0&cancer=11&type=2&statistic=1&prevalence=1&population_group=0&ages_group%5B%5D=0&ages_group%5B%5D=17&nb_items=5&group_cancer=1&include_nmsc=1&include_nmsc_other=1&projection=globe&color_palette=default&map_scale=quantize&map_nb_colors=5&continent=0&rotate=%255B10%252C0%255D).